# buffering period sei in JM reference codec

Tags: ffmpeg, h.264, libavcodec, x264, mpeg-4

Can I know how to encode yuv420 video using JM such that each IDR frame must be associated with Buffering period SEI and picture timing SEI messages. I went through the "encoder.cfg" configure file but i coudn't find any options to enable buffering period SEI and picture timing SEI messages. Also when I went through the encoder code, I observed that nowhere they are updating the parameter "**seiBufferingPeriod.nal_initial_cpb_removal_delay**" present in buffering period SEI. I would like to know whether JM supports Buffering period and picture timing SEI's or not. If supports how to configure encoder and where they are updating the buffering period SEI parameters in the JM encoder.